# how to use xlim in pyplot to plot timestamp

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot timestamp by using pyplot. I want to limit timestamp on x axis in a required range from the timestamp data column in df. I am not getting how to go about it.

I tried using xlim with pandas timestamp option to set limits but it didn't work. Datatype of timestamp in the dataframe is datetime64.

```
   plt.xlim((pd.Timestamp(x[0:1]['Time']), pd.Timestamp(x[35:36]['Time'])
```

Obtained output is:

TypeError: Cannot convert input [0   2017-01-01 06:00:00
Name: Time, dtype: datetime64[ns]] of type  to Timestamp

expected result is :

on x axis I want ticks ranging from a particular timestamp to another particular timestamp taken from the same df.

Comment: What is not working? What are you getting as the output? Since you seem to be new to Stack Overflow, you should read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: do you just want to set the axis limits, disregarding of tick placement? What `dtype` is your `'Time'` column?

Comment: @Sheldore , Now I have edited. Please see if it is comprehensible or not. Thank you for suggestion.

Comment: @cripcate it is datetime64. Tick placement also I want to define. I am learning it step by step.

Comment: could you try just `plt.xlim(x['Time'][0],x['Time'][35])`?

Comment: @Veeresh Sajjan, it is nice to hear, I am happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. I made an answer of my comment with a short explaination, if this answer helped you solving your issue, please mark it as accepted. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`matplotlib` can handle `datetime64` objects, you don't need to convert them to `Timestamp`, so you can use:

```
plt.xlim(x['Time'][0],x['Time'][35])
```

For readability reasons, you can also just write e.g. `[35]`, instead of `[35:36]`, because you only need one objects and not a range.

If you would like to know why the convertion did not work, you can show us the values for `x['Time'][0]` and `x['Time'][35]`.